# Releasing CGMutablePathRef from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I am storing CGMutablePathRefs inside of a NSMutableArray via NSValue.

Like so:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CreateMutablePath();
[self.myArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:path]];
```

In my dealloc, I have tried this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];

    for (int i = 0; i < self.myArray.count;) {

        NSValue *currentPath = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:i];

        CGMutablePathRef path = (CGMutablePathRef)[currentPath pointerValue];

        CGPathRelease(path);
    }

    self.myArray = nil;

}
```

However, when I run this, I get the following exception:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x16b250: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is and how I should correctly release the CGMutablePathRefs?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: At first glance your deallocation code looks correct — except that you should send `[super dealloc]` **at the end** of your `-dealloc` method. This might be related to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[super dealloc]` **must always be the last line of your `dealloc`**.

You do not *ever* want to release objects in an array in that fashion.   Let the array manage the memory.

I.e.:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CreateMutablePath();
[self.myArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:path]];
CGPathRelease(path);
```

And:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
   self.myArray = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t that `CGPathRelease()` deallocate the path? `NSValue` treats it like a `void *` pointer so it won’t retain it… or will it?

Comment: The [`valueWithPointer:` docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000177-valueWithPointer_) do indeed indicate that you should not free the memory at the pointer while the `NSValue` object exists. @Bavarious

Answer (score 0):

While I appreciate Bavarious' and bbum's correction about the placement of the [super dealloc] that wasn't really my problem. In my actual code, I am calling the "releasing" code in a separate method. I placed it inline in dealloc here because I was trying to simplify my question and mistakenly pasted it in the wrong place.

I think the problem wasn't in code, but an environmental issue.  I brought the code over to a different machine and did not experiencing any problems.  I rebooted the original machine and it too is behaving correctly now.  I guess I was in a weird state or something.